# Write a script in Ruby to rename all *.htm files to *.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to write a script in Ruby to rename all *.htm files to *.html in a given
directory.

I've been given a script with some pieces missing.

I need to "METHOD" with the appropriate method name and "REGEX" with an appropriate
regular expression to match all the files that end in `.htm`.

```
Dir.METHOD("*.htm").each do |html_file|
  FileUtils.METHOD html_file, "#{html_file.METHOD(/REGEX/,'.html')}"
end
```

Does anyone know what I should replace "METHOD" and "REGEX" with?

Comment: Have you researched the documentation on `Dir` and `FileUtils`? You should browse the methods for those Ruby classes and determine what makes sense. This documentation is all online. Just do a Google search on "ruby FileUtils", for example. They've done most of the work for you. If you've tried specific things, then please show what you've tried and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Hi @lurker I read all the documentations regarding 'Dir' & 'FileUtils' and nothing could help me still.

To open up a bit more am doing a course program in coursera and I watched the relevant videos and read the supplementary documents and I have completed all my tasks.

Comment: Now am stucked at the practice Quiz where they have given me the code and I have to do the proper modifications I tried replacing so many methods in `Dir` & `FileUtils` but it doesn't work. But for my knowledge am quiet sure that the Methods which should be replaced by the 'Dir' & 'FileUtils' are okay (`Dir glob` & `FileUtils mv`) , I believe the changes should happen in `#{html_file.METHOD(/REGEX/,'.html')}` this part

Comment: If you have a new, different question, you need to ask it separately from this one. If you add it as a comment, it will get lost. If you actually tried some things for this particular question specifically, then you should show what you've tried (edit the question) so you can get a specific response. But again, only if it's part of the *same* question that doesn't invalidate answers given already.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dir.glob("*.htm") do |html_file|
 FileUtils.mv(html_file, "#{File.basename(html_file, ".htm")}.html")
end
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your interest on answering my question, btw I tried your code I do get some syntax error. I tried to look in to the error I don't see anything wrong though. I also have attached the screenshot of the error for your kind consideration.
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SvikQ0R_wVDHaTnzTST7f8SvjQFaCboG]

Comment: @Shaahin that link gives me an HTTP 404 error. I suspect, though, you didn't include the file utilities. You need `require 'fileutils'` to use `FileUtils`.

Comment: Hi thanks for all our answers, I got it right with your replys. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

```
Dir.glob("*.htm").each do |html_file|  
  FileUtils.mv html_file, "#{html_file.sub(/.htm/,'.html')}"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I did it though it did not use a FileUtils method and I skipped ahead and did string manipulation before it was discussed in the lessons.

```
Dir.glob("*.htm") {|old_filename|             #Save file names w/ .htm to old_
   tmp_filename = old_filename.slice(0..-5)   #Remove (.htm) the file extension
   new_filename = tmp_filename + '.html'      #Append the .html extension
   puts new_filename                          #Display renamed file names
}
```